# Why is my button triggering without click in RxJs fromEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have 2 questions about the same thing.

Firstly, is this the correct way to submit a form in RxJs?
I am trying to subscribe to a mouseEvent and if it's a click it'll make a POST request to my backend

so in react I'm doing this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const mouseClick$ = fromEvent(buttonEl.current, 'click').subscribe(console.log('hi123'))
})
```

the console.log is where I'll perform my API POST eventually. however, whenever I reload my page, it's immediately logging out `hi123`, why is this?

```
  <button ref={buttonEl}>
        Submit
    </button>
```

why is this happening? I was hoping the subscribes would only get triggered on click (which by the way they arent at the moment only on load :/)

Answer (score 1):

Because `useEffect` is called when your component is mounted and in your case (because you have no dependecy array) for every update.

You don't need `useEffect` to process a form, just create a regular function, such as `onSubmit` and process your form there

Comment: yes I can do this but I'm trying to learn RxJs and so I want to utilise this functionality

Comment: It won't work in your case, because `useEffect` will always be called once when you load your page. However you can use `useEffect` to initialize the form data for example

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribe` function accepts a function. You should call `console.log()`  from a function.

Bascially you are passing the result of `console.log()` which is `undefined`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const mouseClick$ = fromEvent(buttonEl.current, 
'click').subscribe(evt => console.log('hi123'))
    // Unsubscribe, when the conponent is unmounted:
    return () => mouseClick$.unsubscribe();
})
```